# The most elegant way to check if all elements in a Boolean array are TRUE in C

Tags: c, arrays, boolean

What is the most elegant way to check if all elements within a Boolean array are TRUE without looping over the array in C?

Comment: Maybe x86-assembly voodoo with `REPNE SCASB` but I'd be hard pressed to think of a bona fide justification *not* to use a loop ... (Break out of the loop on the first `False.`)

Comment: Without looping?   How do you go through an array without looping?

Comment: If you can be certain that `bool` is implemented in the typical way, you could use `memchr`.  Though that's really just offloading your loop to another function (but one which the compiler should optimize well).

Comment: But if the length of the array is not known in advance, I think one could prove that some sort of loop is required, though it may or may not look like one.  Again, it would help to explain why you think you want to avoid a loop: what is your use case?  This sounds like an X-Y problem on its face.

Comment: You could amortize the checking and the updates using a counter. Increment the counter every time you change an array element from false to true. Decrement the counter every time you change from true to false. This could be done using a function to update an array element and the counter at the same time. Then to test if all elements are true, you just need to check the counter.

Comment: Without looping?   When only 1 element in the array test it, else test the 2 halves of the array.. (Recursion).

Answer (score 1):

***If*** you need 64 or fewer boolean fields, then you can use a 64-bit long bit-field.
Each bit corresponds to a single boolean entry.

To check if any bit is set:

```
uint64_t bit_array_64 = 0ull;            // Make an empty bit-field
bit_array_64 = bit_array_64 | (1 << 9);  // Set one random bit ON.

bool is_any_set = !!bit_array_64;        // !! will now return "true"
```

Comment: And "is all set"?

Comment: is all set: `bit_array_64 == -1` should do

Comment: problem with an array of booleans as bits is that each time you read or write a bit you read 64 bits. Not just 8. Otherwise it's a nice solution.

Comment: Trying to compare to `-1` is sloppy, and will likely generate a "signed/unsigned mismatch comparison" warning.   I'd much prefer `(bit_array_64 == UINT64_MAX)`.

Comment: much better, yes.

Comment: If the array length is less than or equal to 64, this will test for all bits 1: `bit_array_64 == (UINT64_MAX >> (64 - len))`.

Comment: Adding an artificial limit was not in the original description.  Additionally, packing bits into an unsigned int, and then testing for -1 is really messy and may not always give you want you expect and thus not very elegant.  A simple loop though each of the entries in the array and if any are false, break out of the loop and if the resulting counter does not equal the number of entries in the array, then false, otherwise, true.

Comment: To test if all bits are set, I would just write `!~bit_array_64`.

Comment: How are you going to get from your 'bit field' to the long you're comparing?

Comment: `ll` not needed in `0ull` - but may be instructive.  `1` in `1 << 9` without `ull` is a problem with larger random shift values.